# Can't replace div using regex

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have the following code from lines `6-20`

```html
            <div>
                1
            </div>
            <div>
                2
            </div>
            <div>
                3
            </div>
            <div>
                4
            </div>
            <div>
                5
            </div>
```

I want to replace all `<div> {anything here} </div>` with none.

I tried the following

1. `:%s/<div>\W+.\W+div>//`
2. `:6,20s/<div>\W+.\W+div>//`
3. `:6,20s/<div>\W+.\W+div>/\0/`
4. `:%s/<div>\W+.\W+div>/\0/`

Nothing works. It says `Pattern not found`

But when I search with this
`/<div>\W+.\W+div>`

It shows that there are `5` matches

How to achieve this substitution?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This regexp (all of them really) isn't really valid in Vim, since the `+` is not a valid metacharacter and will only match a literal `+`, so I'm not sure how you're getting 5 matches... This regexp should work: `/<div>\_.\{-}<\/div>/`, can you check whether it works for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with the regex, though filbranden has some thoughts in the comments.

To solve the issue, though, [I would do something a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4400820): `:global/<div>/normal! dat` (delete the tag on the lines with an opening `div` tag).

Comment: I think `dst` is a vim-surround extension. The built-in `dat` does work for that, though.

Comment: Oh, crud, I forgot they wanted to delete everything between the tags, too /facepalm @filbranden